# Database migration issue in Ruby_on_Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, bootstrap-4

I am now creating a teacher registration form using Ruby on Rails. I did not create a database to store the Data of users. Is it possible to create a database to store all the users data in the middle of the progress? If possible how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a database by using following

```
rake db:create
```

These will create database for you.

Comment: Thank you lg86, I already did the above step but it didnt work. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create the database using the following

```
1) rake db:create

2) rake db:migrate
```

Note:

Step 1) will only create the database

While 2) will migrate the table with its attributes to the database created in step 1) .

For Step 2) you need to first generate model using the following command:

```
rails g model User name email
```

then use step 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohan